# help with clone and appendTo in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my DOM:

```
    <div class="group">
        <div class="comment">
            <button class="addLink">Add link</button>
        </div>

        <div class="link">
            <button class="removeLink">Remove link</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I wanna click on the button.addLink and it will copy the div.link and append it as last child in div.group.

i started out with this code but got stuck.

```
 $(this).parent().parent().children(':last').clone().appendTo();
```

i dont know how to write appendTo. cause i want it to be appended to div.group but i cant just type it as 'div.group' cause there will be a lot of other div.group so i have to select it from a relational point of view.

could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().parent().children(':last').clone().appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
```

Or a bit nicer:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
$parent.children(':last').clone().appendTo($parent);
```

[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) accepts a parameter as *target* where the elements should be appended to.

You should read the API documentation, it is well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".addLink").click(function() {
    var clone = $(this).parent().next("div.link").clone();
    $(this).closest(".group").append(clone);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).next()...` should be `$(this).parent().next()` to traverse to the `<div class="link">`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button.addLink").click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var linkDiv = self.parent().next().clone();
    self.parent().parent().append(linkDiv);    
});
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/odayu/edit)**. Click on the Preview button and try the code out.

Answer (score 0):

Try .parents()

```
$('.addlink').click(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parents('div.group');
   parent.children(':last').clone().appendTo(parent);
});
```

Comment: `parents` can deliver more than one element. It also traverses up to the root node. karim79's approach with `closest` is much better in this case, see `parents` vs `closest` here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/